# RMarkdown: Option to control number of results per page in SQL results?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I've written an SQL chunk in my RMarkdown document:

````
```{sql, connection = con, max.print = 300}
      select * from myTable
```
````

This prints 300 rows as expected in a pretty table when I run the chunk within RStudio.

However, I'd like to be able to control how many results show up on the first page of the printed table--right now, RStudio displays 10 rows per page along with page controls to jump to whatever page I'm interested in.

Is there a code chunk option I can use to control how many results are displayed per page in the results table?

For whatever it's worth, I'm really only interested in in-line code execution--I don't really care about what happens when I knit the document, only what appears when I run the chunk within RStudio.

Comment: As a bit of background, what I'm really hoping for is some sort of lightweight SQL client so that I can be reminded what table and column names in my database are while I'm working in RStudio. 

Using an Rmarkdown chunk in another tab provides a vague sort of solution, but I suspect, based on the answer below that says there aren't options at this point to display all the results at once, I might as well just find something else/different.

Comment: A follow-up comment, several month later: the terminal tab in RStudio provides the sort of client I was looking for--I can run the MySQL client in the terminal and run throwaway SQL queries there. The output isn't as pretty, but it's easy and accessible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this (changing 25 to the number of rows you're after):

````
```{sql, connection = con, rows.print = 25}
select * from myTable
```
````

You can find more chunk options [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#paged-printing).

Answer (score 1):

There are no chunk options.  I'd recommend you print subsets for each page:

````
```{r page_1, results = 'asis'}
df[1:25,]
```
#

```{r page_2, results = 'asis'}
df[26:250,]
```
````

And so forth.

Comment: Too bad. Maybe we'll see that sort of thing added in the future.